# Nesting Functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

In the JS below - I am trying to nest a function so that I don't have to repeat the "add field" for each field in the form.

However - The alert 'Trogdor!' only shows up if it's placed before `addfield('rcname', 'RC Name');`

As a result, the incrementals (i and n) are not updating either of course.

Is something wrong with the syntax?

```js
function addcameragroup() {
    var newcamgroup = document.createElement("div");
    newcamgroup.setAttribute("id", "camera-" + i);
    var camform = document.getElementById('formtable');
    camform.appendChild(newcamgroup);

    function addfield(fieldname, fieldtxt) {
        var newformrow = document.createElement("div");
        newcamgroup.appendChild(newformrow);
        newformrow.setAttribute("class", "formrow");
        var fieldlabel = document.createElement("label");
        newformrow.appendChild(fieldlabel);
        fieldlabel.setAttribute("for", fieldname);
        fieldlabel.innerHTML(fieldtxt);
    }

    addfield('rcname', 'RC Name');
    alert('Trogdor!');
    i++;
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Typically, if code stops, you're getting an error.  Do you see any console messages?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein that's pretty much the only possibility here

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Yes - sorry I didn't include it: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'innerHTML' of object #<HTMLLabelElement> is not a function`

Looks like it might have to do with the fact that fieldlabel is a document.dcreateElement Label? But I don't know how to refer to it by the attribute "for" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @ScottMermelstein. Ben's answer below was the error causing it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662329/1543447

Comment: Ha!  My help was minimal, but glad to provide it.  I already upvoted Ben's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fieldlabel.innerHTML(fieldtxt);
```

should be

```
fieldlabel.innerHTML = fieldtxt;
```

innerHTML is not a function its an attribute. Trying to call that is causing an error and making your program stop executing.  You should look into learning about the debugging and developer tools for your favorite browser.

MDN Docs for innerHTML: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)

Comment: Thanks, Ben! That worked. Oddly enough I started in HTML and PHP - and completely skipped JS. I will dive into it. Again - thanks!